# SaxParseException content of element include must match EMPTY

Tags: properties, include, mybatis

Executing Mybatis 3.2.8 I am using the element "property" as content for element "include", as stated in the documentation:

http://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/es/sqlmap-xml.html

```html
<select id="selectUsers" resultType="map">
  select
    <include refid="userColumns"><property name="alias" value="t1"/></include>,
    <include refid="userColumns"><property name="alias" value="t2"/></include>
  from some_table t1
    cross join some_table t2
</select>
```

When I try to execute the above code I get the error: SaxParseException content of element include must match EMPTY

I downloaded the [DTD](http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd) and it is correct:

```html
<!-- Dynamic -->

<!ELEMENT include (property+)?>
<!ATTLIST include
refid CDATA #REQUIRED
>
```

So, why am I getting the Exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after some digging into the sources of MyBatis I get an explanation:

DTD in version 3.2.8:

```html
<!-- Dynamic -->

<!ELEMENT include EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST include
refid CDATA #REQUIRED
>
```

DTD on version 3.3.0 (currently pointed by http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd):

```html
<!-- Dynamic -->

<!ELEMENT include (property+)?>
<!ATTLIST include
refid CDATA #REQUIRED
>
```

So simply upgrade from version 3.2.8 to version 3.3.0 and all will go fine again